# Ending A Function In Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, tkinter

I have an looped function in python using Tkinter, and when I press a button using Tkinter it does not end. It continues to the new function that has been specified by the button but it continues on with the old function aswell

Here is the code (Part Of It):

```
def countdown(self):

        if self.seconds <= 0:
            if self.minutes > 0:
                self.seconds += 59
                self.minutes -= 1
            elif self.minutes == 0:
                if self.hours != 0:
                    self.minutes += 59
                    self.seconds += 59
                    self.hours -= 1
                else:
                    self.timerLab.configure(text="Times Up!")

        self.timerLab.configure(text="Time Remaining: %d:%d:%d " % (self.hours,self.minutes,self.seconds))
        self.seconds -= 1
        self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

So how do I end this once another button is pushed. Is there something that ends the current process?

Comment: Can't you place a module level boolen variable called isRunning? Make it true when your start button is pressed, and false when stop is pressed. Inside this countdown() function, you will have to check for that variable being true in order to continue..

Comment: Yes this would probably solve it

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter offers a solution to this problem with the [`after_cancel()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method. You have to store the "after identifier" returned by `after` and pass it to `after_cancel`:

```
def start_countdown(self):
    if self.after_id is not None:
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
    self.countdown()

def countdown(self):
    # ...
    self.after_id = self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with stopping it with Ctrl+C there's a number of methods to implement this. I'm not an expert on them, but from a quick Google search it looks like something along the lines of this could work:

```
import signal 
import sys
import subprocess

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
    sys.exit(0)
```

There's also [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146066-exiting-a-loop-with-a-single-key-press/) solution, which exits on ESC (You just change 27 to the number of another key to change that):

```
import msvcrt

while 1:
    print 'Testing..'
    # body of the loop ...
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
    if ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27:
        break
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i was trying to fix the problem by simply pressing a button on the app not the keyboard. I am sorry if you misunderstood but to be honest this will come in handy for future programs so thankyou :)

Comment: Oh! Really sorry about that, completely misunderstood. I'm afraid I won't be able to help you with that then, don't have any experience with it. Glad to hear that my "answer" was of some use, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a button that sets a variable. Have your countdown function check that variable, and only re-schedule itself if the variable is set to a specific value.

Something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.running = False

    start_button = Button(..., self.start, ...)
    quit_button = Button(..., self.stop, ...)

def start(self):
    self.running = True;
    self.countdown()

def stop(self):
    self.running = False;

def countdown(self):
    ...
    if (self.running):
        self.after(1000, self.countdown)
```

Answer (score -2):

> Is there something that ends the current process

To stop the current mainloop and destroy all widgets; you could call `root.destroy()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from Tkinter import Tk, Button

def counter(root, n=0):
    sys.stderr.write("\r%3s" % n)
    root.after(1000, counter, root, n + 1)

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack()
counter(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the code does what it says it does; I'd appreciate the explanation of the downvote.

Comment: The OP asks a way to stop calling the callback function of  `after`, not how to exit the mainloop. I'm sorry if you disagree with the downvote, but `destroy` has nothing to do with scheduled functions.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I see your point. I've interpreted the question (it seems incorrectly) as the OP wants to shutdown the GUI hence `root.destroy()` rather than to cancel the callback chain with `.after_cancel()` (more appropriate in this case). btw, I don't mind downvotes if the reason is clear (it is a useful feedback).